# Is there a name for a condition that prevents a loop or recursion from running forever?

Tags: loops, recursion

```
while(someConditionIsTrue) {

}
```

or

```
function someFunction(n) {
  if(someConditionIsTrue) {
      return n;
  } else {
      return n * someFunction(n - 1);
}
```

Is there a name for someConditionIsTrue?

Comment: In case someone wants to know it's called a PREDICAT. Essentially predicat is an ASSERTION with a variable element.

Comment: For instance 0 < 7 is an assertion (an expression that evaluates to true or false), but  x < 7 is a predicat (the result [true or false] depends on the value of the unknown)